Connect to two separate networks using a Raspberry PI 5?
Is it possible to connect to two separate networks with a Raspberry PI 5, one using the Wifi interface where a Web application is accessible by a fixed known IP and another where the Ethernet interface gets an IP by DHCP based on its MAC address?


What have you tried?  Why didn't it work? See https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=378054

NOTE you are NOT "create(ing) two separate networks" but accessing them (the networks must exist) although it is unclear WHY you would WANT a static IP (unless you are attempting to create an Access Point on the Pi - in which case the arrow should point the other way).

of course it is possible, Linux is a very powerful operating system

A static IP is useful if you do not want to rely on MDNS hostnames etc., and if configured properly (which should usually include an explicit reservation on the router), will work without problems.

If you expect an answer that might help move you closer to your stated objective, you will have to disclose what changes you've made with Network Manager - or nmcli if you're using the "Lite" version of the OS. If you don't understand what I'm saying, start with this search.


Is it possible to connect to two separate networks with a Raspberry PI 5

Yes, the two interfaces are independent of one another and would have different addresses and the full range of ports (opening a specific listen port can apply to all, some, or just one interface); the system will then route traffic to one or the other based on destination.
